How to separate noise and signal in a histogram
I have a histogramme who represent the max amplitude of 3000 signal + noise and this come from infrared detector. so, the signal is a number of photon. I want to normalized the histogram in function of the number of photon. Thus if I take 0 photon I only get the noise. But When I done all of that I get the same hstogramme with juste a different standard deviation and if I choose 0 photon I have a Dirac and not just my noise so I'm a little bit lost to what I need (other histo, new parameter, more data ???).
I hope someone have a solution maybe with the use of this parameters ?
Maybe use the parameters : SNR = mean(Amax)/Std or QEFR = SNR/Nbph or F= QE/QEFR with QE is the quantum efficency and SNR singnal noise ration.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.special import gamma
from scipy.signal import convolve

# Quantum Efficiency
QE = 0.72
k1 = 6

# Optical power and number of photons
optical_power_dBm = 77.12
num_photons = 37

# File paths for the files containing the maximum amplitudes
file_amplitude_max_with = r'C:\***\amplitudes_max_signal_bruit_9V_C1.txt'
file_amplitude_max_without = r'C:\***\amplitudes_max_signal_bruit_9V_C1_sans.txt'
# Load maximum amplitudes from files
amplitudes_max_noise_with = np.loadtxt(file_amplitude_max_with)
amplitudes_max_noise_without = np.loadtxt(file_amplitude_max_without)

# Normalize amplitudes to rotate around 1
mean_amplitude_with = np.mean(amplitudes_max_noise_with)
mean_amplitude_without = np.mean(amplitudes_max_noise_without)

# Normalize amplitudes to rotate around 1 photon
normalized_amplitudes_max_noise_with = amplitudes_max_noise_with / (mean_amplitude_with * 37)
normalized_amplitudes_max_noise_without = amplitudes_max_noise_without / (mean_amplitude_without * 37)

normalized_amplitudes_max_noise_with = normalized_amplitudes_max_noise_with * 37
normalized_amplitudes_max_noise_with10 = normalized_amplitudes_max_noise_with * 10
normalized_amplitudes_max_noise_with1 = normalized_amplitudes_max_noise_with * 20

normalized_amplitudes_max_noise_without = normalized_amplitudes_max_noise_without * 37

# Calculate the standard deviations of the normalized amplitudes
STD_noise_with = np.std(normalized_amplitudes_max_noise_with)
STD_noise_with1 = np.std(normalized_amplitudes_max_noise_with1)
STD_noise_with10 = np.std(normalized_amplitudes_max_noise_with10)
STD_noise_without = np.std(normalized_amplitudes_max_noise_without)

# Convert the standard deviations to the number of noise photons
n_photon_noise_with = STD_noise_with * num_photons
n_photon_noise_with1 = STD_noise_with1 * num_photons
n_photon_noise_with10 = STD_noise_with10 * num_photons
n_photon_noise_without = STD_noise_without * num_photons

print('standard deviation with =', STD_noise_with)
print('standard deviation with1 =', STD_noise_with1)
print('standard deviation with10 =', STD_noise_with10)
print('standard deviation without =', STD_noise_without)

print('number of photons without cover', n_photon_noise_with)
print('number of photons without cover', n_photon_noise_with1)
print('number of photons without cover', n_photon_noise_with10)
print('number of photons with cover', n_photon_noise_without)

# Display the results
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.hist(normalized_amplitudes_max_noise_with, bins=37, alpha=0.7, color='lightblue', label='Normalized Maximum Noise Amplitudes (with) 37')
plt.hist(normalized_amplitudes_max_noise_with10, bins=37, alpha=0.7, label='Normalized Maximum Noise Amplitudes (with) 10')
plt.hist(normalized_amplitudes_max_noise_with1, bins=37, alpha=0.7, label='Normalized Maximum Noise Amplitudes (with) 20')
plt.hist(normalized_amplitudes_max_noise_without, bins=37, alpha=0.7, color='red', label='Normalized Maximum Noise Amplitudes (without) 37')
plt.xlabel('Amplitude (Normalized)')
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.title('Distribution of Normalized Maximum Noise Amplitudes')
plt.legend()
plt.grid()

plt.show()



divide by the mean amplitude and scaling to the number of photons. calculate std deviation. assess signal quality relative to noise. plot histograms
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

QE = 0.72
k1 = 6

optical_power_dBm = 77.12
num_photons = 37

file_amplitude_max_with = r'C:\***\amplitudes_max_signal_bruit_9V_C1.txt'
file_amplitude_max_without = r'C:\***\amplitudes_max_signal_bruit_9V_C1_sans.txt'

amplitudes_max_noise_with = np.loadtxt(file_amplitude_max_with)
amplitudes_max_noise_without = np.loadtxt(file_amplitude_max_without)

mean_amplitude_with = np.mean(amplitudes_max_noise_with)
mean_amplitude_without = np.mean(amplitudes_max_noise_without)

normalized_amplitudes_max_noise_with = amplitudes_max_noise_with / mean_amplitude_with * num_photons
normalized_amplitudes_max_noise_without = amplitudes_max_noise_without / mean_amplitude_without * num_photons

STD_noise_with = np.std(normalized_amplitudes_max_noise_with)
STD_noise_without = np.std(normalized_amplitudes_max_noise_without)

n_photon_noise_with = STD_noise_with
n_photon_noise_without = STD_noise_without

print('Standard deviation (with signal) =', STD_noise_with)
print('Standard deviation (without signal) =', STD_noise_without)
print('Number of photons (noise, with signal) =', n_photon_noise_with)
print('Number of photons (noise, without signal) =', n_photon_noise_without)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.hist(normalized_amplitudes_max_noise_with, bins=37, alpha=0.7, color='lightblue', label='Normalized Maximum Noise Amplitudes (with signal)')
plt.hist(normalized_amplitudes_max_noise_without, bins=37, alpha=0.7, color='red', label='Normalized Maximum Noise Amplitudes (without signal)')
plt.xlabel('Amplitude (Normalized)')
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.title('Distribution of Normalized Maximum Noise Amplitudes')
plt.legend()
plt.grid()

plt.show()

